# How to get Latitude and Longitude from google maps latLng Object

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-maps

I integrated angular google maps with my application to get the latitude and longitude of a certain place by dragging a marker.I successfully returned an object which encapsulates the latitude and longitude fields but I am not knowing how to access them and assign them to local variables in my application.Any idea ?
Here is a picture of my chrome console

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you have a `.` at the end of `lat()` instead of a `;` which is messing up your code. Try this:

```
this.latitude = $event.latLng.lat();
this.longitude = $event.latLng.lng();
```

Comment: hey poul , yes I know of that mistake , my problem is that the data I need is complexly nested, I can't seem to figure out how to reach it

Comment: @HasanKanaan you should post some code, with what you expect, and with what you tried (not a screenshot)